# использовать в запросе id, которая является первичным ключом IDENTITY другой записи, которая будет создана MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо написать SQL запрос (создание сущности=>взять id этой сущности=>использовать этот id в другом запросе.)

Возникла проблема с частью запроса взять id созданной сущности.
Вроде, мне необходимо использовать DECLARE, но как в нее положить поле Id из сущности, которую я создал.

```
DECLARE @Document_Id AS INT
SET @Document_Id = ????? (не знаю как вставить)
INSERT INTO DocumentsBook(Entity, Entity2, Entity3, Entity4)
VALUES ('datetime','1','1','11')
```

Т.Е как мне положить в @Document_Id DocumentId из вставленной записи, если она первичный ключ и я не могу знать, под каким номером она создастся

Comment: можно использовать @@identity, scope_identity() и через OUTPUT при вставке/обновлении

Comment: `scope_identity` в помощь

Comment: *(не знаю как вставить)* Ну вообще-то сперва надо вставить запись, и только потом получать сгенерённый ID. Так, чисто логически... Да, у тебя там на пять полей всего 4 значения - нехорошо...

Comment: вообще, вероятно, у человека вопрос о том, как сделать чтобы `documentId` генерировалось автоматически, а не о том, чтобы взять значение из другой вставленной записи. для этого надо отметить столбец как `IDENTITY`, и далее вообще исключить сам столбец из insert запроса

Comment: @Akina да, вы правы, перепроверил insert и он не отрабатывал, т.к. указал лишнее поле. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При условии, что поле DocumentId является IDENTITY:

```
DECLARE @Document_Id AS INT;
Declare @t table (id int);

INSERT INTO DocumentsBook(Entity, Entity2, Entity3, Entity4)
OUTPUT inserted.DocumentId INTO @t(id)
VALUES ('datetime','1','1','11')

SET @Document_Id = (SELECT id FROM @t);
```

Comment: отлично, спасибо. Да, полеDocumentId явлется IDENTITY